# Есть ли здесь ошибки?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Зуевское яйцо не подделает никто.

Answer (score 1):

Запись правильная: Зуевское яйцо не подделает никто (прописная буква в начале предложения).

Зуевская птицефабрика - имя собственное, первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, зуевское яйцо - продукция птицефабрики, пишется со строчной буквы без кавычек, например: оптовая цена на зуевское яйцо.